# How to Loop BasicNameValuePair in Java

Tags: java, php

I am trying to Loop BasicNameValuePair using Java.
I already have one working example in PHP.
Here is what I have:

```
 ArrayList<NameValuePair> data = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
 postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", username));
 postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", password));

 public String sign_creator(ArrayList data){
    String sig = "";
    for(String key : data ){
        String value = data[key];
        sig += "" + key + "=" + value + "";
    }
    sig += "62f8ce9f74b12f84c123cc23437a4a32";
    sig = md5(sig);
    return data['sig'] = sig;
}
```

I am trying to implement this PHP logic in Java

```
$data = array(
"email" => @$_GET['u'],
"password" => @$_GET['p'],
);

function sign_creator(&$data){
    $sig = "";
    foreach($data as $key => $value){
        $sig .= "$key=$value";
    }
    $sig .= "62f8ce9f74b12f84c123cc23437a4a32";
    $sig = md5($sig);
    return $data['sig'] = $sig;
}
```

Comment: data contains BasicNameValuePair, so you should do for(BasicNameValuePair namevalue: data)

Comment: please show output of your java code

Comment: output returns errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things supported by PHP work differently in Java.

1. In Java, values are never passed by reference, only by value.
2. Associative arrays like those in PHP don't exist, in Java they're using `HashMap`s. However, a `List` with `NameValuePair`s is also possible.
3. String literals like `'sig'` must be written in double quotes.
4. Variables can't be used inside string literals, so `"$key=$value"` won't work.

You are almost there, you just need to change a few things in the code:

```
// I guess you're using org.apache.commons.httpclient.NameValuePair

void addSign(List<NameValuePair> data) {
    String sig = "";
    for (NameValuePair pair : data) {
        sig += pair.getName() + "=" + pair.getValue();
    }
    sig += "62f8ce9f74b12f84c123cc23437a4a32";
    sig = md5(sig); // I assume you have an md5 method somewhere.

    // You need to add the sig to the list
    data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sig", sig));
}
```

*Note: You shouldn't use MD5, as it's being considered insecure. See [this article](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure).*

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Map for this purpose. I assume you are trying to create signature for a single user using username and password. So, you can return the signature from the sign_creator method .  Here is the sample -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String,String> data = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
    data.put("email", "abcd");
    data.put("password", "asadsabcd");;
    System.out.println(sign_creator(data));
   }
   public static String sign_creator(Map<String ,String> data){
    String sig = "";
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> keyValPair : data.entrySet() ){
        String value = keyValPair.getValue();
        sig += "" + keyValPair.getKey() + "=" + value + "";
    }
    sig += "62f8ce9f74b12f84c123cc23437a4a32";
    sig = md5(sig);
    return  sig;
}
```

Comment: But I have to send these parameter to httpclient

Comment: public String sign_creator(ArrayList<NameValuePair> data){
     String sig = "";
     for(NameValuePair keyvalPair : data ){
         String value = keyvalPair.getValue();
         sig += "" + keyvalPair.getKey() + "=" + value + "";
     }
     sig += "62f8ce9f74b12f84c123cc23437a4a32";
     sig = md5(sig);
     return data.add( new org.apache.commons.httpclient.Header("sig",    sig));
 }